# How to find the value of a select_tag using JQuery using Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to find the value of a select_tag in Rails 4 using JQuery. Once I have the value I want to update the view with a partial containing radio buttons.

My code is not working. Can you let me know what I am doing wrong.

**index.html.erb file**

```
<%= form_tag experts_path, method: :get do %>
    <p>
      <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
    <hr>

    <h3>Skills Categories</h3>
        <%= select_tag "skill_categories", options_from_collection_for_select(@skill_categories, "id", "category"), prompt: "All Skills" %>

    <div class="skills"></div>
<% end %>

<script>
$( "#skill_categories" ).change(function() {
    var category_from_select = $(".skills").find(":selected").text();
    $(".skills").replaceWith("<div class='skills'><%=j render 'experts/skills', selected_category: category_from_select %></div>");
});
</script>
```

**_skills/html.erb partial**

```
<h4>Skills</h4>
<% skill_all.each do |skill| %>
    <%= radio_button_tag "skills[]", "#{skill.name}",
                         ((params[:skills] != nil) && (params[:skills].index(skill.name) != nil) ? true : false) %>
    <%= skill.name %>
<% end %>
```

**experts_controller.erb**

```
  def skills_search
    @skills = Skill.all
  end
```

**experts_helper.erb**

```
module ExpertsHelper

  def skill_all
    @skills = Skill.all
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change:

```
var category_from_select = $(".skills").find(":selected").text();
```

to:

```
var category_from_select = $(this).find(":selected").text();
```

To get selected option, you need `select` element with`#skill_categories` not `div` with `.skills`

Comment: Thanks @Felix. I tried this and got the following error:         undefined local variable or method `category_from_select' for #<#<Class:0x0000010154d6a0>:0x000001022fb888>

Comment: @miggitty are you sure you don't need to concatenate using `+` here: `selected_category: category_from_select` since `category_from_select` is a variable?